# MySQL problem: Merging multiple results/rows caused by n-m

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

i tried now nearly everything i could to solve he following problem. So far with no success. But there must be a solution cause i dont think the case is s.th too special. I think i am just a bloody beginner ;-) I need to join union merge or whatever ;-) in MySQL to solve the following problem...

CASE: Three tables "posts", "tagmap" and "tags"

The **tagmap** table stores all n-m relations the id's of the posts and the id's of the tags
The **tags** table stores the **tag_name** with the **tag** id
The **posts** table stores the **post_title** and the **post_id**

```
 posts    post_id    post_title
          1          Charlie Chaplin Painting

 tagmap   id         post_id    tag_id
          100        1          12
          101        1          13
          102        1          14

 tags     tag_id     tag_name
          12         Acryl
          13         Chalk
          14         Poster
```

**What i am trying to achieve is to get a result as the follwing where all related tags are merged in one column. Either by a comma separated list or spaces:**
post_id => 1, post_title => Charlie Chaplin... tag_name => Acryl, Chalk, Poster

**But till now the only thing i could get are mukltiple results like this:**
post_id => 1, post_title => Charlie Chaplin... tag_name => Acryl
post_id => 1, post_title => Charlie Chaplin... tag_name => Chalk
post_id => 1, post_title => Charlie Chaplin... tag_name => Poster

Does anyone know how this could be achieved... Any help would be highly appreciated and thx in advance to everyone who could help me out whith this ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.post_id,
         p.post_title,
         GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name ORDER BY t.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM POSTS p
    JOIN TAGMAP tm ON tm.post_id = p.post_id
    JOIN TAGS t ON t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
GROUP BY p.post_id, p.post_title
```

Reference:

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Yes, that seems correct, sorry, I was looking at more of a UNION result X-)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH... I cant believe that i didnt find that... I really searched for hours... ending up in recursive methods or whatever... Hoped it would be that simple. Just had to add the GROUP_CONCAT and worked like a charme in seconds... THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I only modified it a bit to s.th like  

GROUP_CONCAT... AS tags

Made it easier to read.. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @Booosh: Sorry, yeah - in my haste, I didn't provide a column alias for the `GROUP_CONCAT` column